# What are the origins of "take you up on it"

Tags: etymology, idioms, phrasal-verbs

A common English idiom "take you up on it" is apparently used to indicate a general willingness or predisposition to accept something that is offered or granted. For example,

> If you make an offer to help a stranger in need, don't be surprised if they take you up on it!

Does anyone know the origins of this common English idiom?

Comment: The word *"it"* is just an irrelevant pronoun standing in for the offer that's been made. The "idiomatic" issue is that *"take up [an offer] **made by someone**"* transforms into *"take [someone] up on [an offer]"*. Nor does the pronoun *"you"* make any difference - it's no different with *"I should take John up on his offer"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that part of the informality comes from transforming the verb *take*, which here means something like *accept*, to the phrasal verb *take up [on]*.

[Phrasal verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) often have meanings that are different from the verb they contain and sound more informal than just the verb.

For me there is also the playful imagery of *taking up* meaning something like *absorb*. I picture an amoeba engulfing an "offer particle".